# The max range of Left shift operation

Tags: bit-manipulation

I tried doing a left shift operation for (`2 << 31`) but the result what I got was `0`. I want to know why it resulted in `0` and what will be the max range of `n` in (`2 << n`)?

Comment: you need to add more information there: which languae you are using, and which data type are you using.

Answer (score 0):

2 is 10 in binary and it is stored as 00000000000000000000000000000010 in a 32-bit data. You are trying to shift that 10 towards left by 31. As 10 already occupies 2 places it will jump 31 minus 2 0s towards left. When it reaches the 32nd 0, the '0' from the 10 will be stored in the 32nd place and the '1' will be lost as there is no place after 32. So the result will be 0000000000000000000000000000000 which is 0.